# Convert MOV DV/DVCPRO to MP4 H.264 without significant of quality

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have several media files that are MOV encoded with a format of DV/DVCPRO (which I believe is lossless) NTSC that I need to convert to MP4 using H.264 or some other portable format but without a notable loss of quality.

The originals have a data rate of 30.34 MB/s.

When I convert them using: `ffmpeg -i x.mov x.mp4` I get a file that will not play on my Mac using Quicktime.

When I convert them using `ffmpeg -i x.mov -pix_fmt yuv420p -y x.mp4` I get an output file that will open, but the bitrate is reduced to 864.55 kb/s, roughly a 1:30 reduction in quality. For my purposes this is not adequate. Also, it *appears* the result file is 640x480 (using the 'Get Info' command in Finder) whereas the original shows as 720x480.

So my question is what parameters do I send to ffmpeg to:

- convert the video data to H.264
- keep the quality close to the raw video quality (20-30% reduction is probably OK, but not 97%)
- ensure the video will play back on my Mac using Quicktime

**UPDATE**: changed 'video container' to 'video data'.

Comment: H.264 is not a container format. There's an entire guide to encoding H.264 with FFmpeg on https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264. The QuickTime compatibility link is broken, and possibly outdated, but you can read it on the way-back machine here: http://web.archive.org/web/20141118095252/http://mewiki.project357.com/wiki/X264_Encoding_Suggestions#QuickTime-compatible_Encoding

Comment: I meant 'video data', not 'video container. Thanks, I'll check out the link.

Comment: I think the easiest way is to use `profile` and `crf`. `crf 18` is nearly visually lossless. You can optionally use `tune`. The bugs in QT should be fixed by now so bother only if you need legacy compatibility. Avoid the `veryslow` or a slower preset just in case.

Comment: I can't get the `crf 18` to work, I keep getting encoding errors. Not really sure how to even figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aergistal's answer led me to play around and get a 'good enough' result with:

```
ffmpeg -i "{0}" -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset slow -y "{1}"
```